# HLSL - Global variables are unchanged in Geometry Shader (DirectX11)

Tags: geometry, directx, shader, global, hlsl

My program receives input consists of line segments and expand the lines to cylinder-like object (like the **PipeGS** project in DX SDK sample browser).

I added an array of radius scaling parameter for the pipes, and modify them procedurally, but the radii of pipes just didn't change.

I'm pretty sure the scaling parameters are updated every frame because I set them as the pixel value. When I modify them, the pipes change color while their radii keep unchanged.

So I am wondering if there's any limitation of using global variables in GS and I didn't find it on the internet. (or just wrong keywords I used)

The shader code is like

```
cbuffer {
   .....
   float scaleParam[10];
   .....
}

// Pass 1
VS_1 { // pass through }

// Tessellation stages
// Hull shader, domain shader and patch constant function

GS_1 {
   pipeRadius = MaxRadius * scaleParam[PipeID];
   ....
   // calculate pipe positions base on line-segments and pipeRadius
   ....
   OutputStream.Append ( ... );
}

// Pixel shader is disabled in the first pass

// Pass 2 
VS_2 { // pass through }

// Tessellation stages
// Hull shader, domain shader and patch constant function
// Transform the vertices and normals to world coordinate in DS

// No geometry shader in the second pass

PS_2 
{ 
   return float4( scaleParam[0], scaleParam[1], scaleParam[2], 0.0f );
}
```

Edit:
I shrinked the problem.
There are 2 passes in my program, in the first pass I calculate the line-segment expanding in Geometry Shader and stream-out.

In the second pass, the program receives pipe position from the first pass, tessellate the pipes and apply displacement mapping on them so they can be more detailed.

I can change the surface tessellation factor and pixel color which are in the second pass and see the result on screen immediately.

When I modify the scaleParam, the pipes change color while their radii keep unchanged. It means I did change the scaleParam and pass them into shader correctly but something's wrong in the first pass.

Second edit:

I modified shader code above and post some code of the cpp file here.
In the cpp file:

```
void DrawScene() 
{
    // Update view matrix, TessFactor, scaleParam etc.
    ....
    ....

    // Bind stream-output buffer
    ID3D11Buffer* bufferArray[1] = {mStreamOutBuffer};
    md3dImmediateContext->SOSetTargets(1, bufferArray, 0);

    // Two pass rendering
    D3DX11_TECHNIQUE_DESC techDesc;
    mTech->GetDesc( &techDesc );
    for(UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p)
    {
        mTech->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0, md3dImmediateContext);

        // First pass
        if (p==0) 
        {
            md3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 
                                   &mVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

            md3dImmediateContext->Draw(mVertexCount,0);

            // unbind stream-output buffer
            bufferArray[0] = NULL;
            md3dImmediateContext->SOSetTargets( 1, bufferArray, 0 );
        }
        // Second pass
        else 
        {                
            md3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 
                                   &mStreamOutBuffer, &stride, &offset);

            md3dImmediateContext->DrawAuto();
        }
    }
    HR(mSwapChain->Present(0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using a `float4` position, the w value of vector is a scale for final position in scene, example:

```
float4 pos0 = float4(5, 5, 5, 1);
// is equals that:
float4 pos1 = float4(10, 10, 10, 2);
```

To correct scale a position you must changue only the `.xyz` value of vector position.

Comment: I am using float3 before entering pixel shader. I can scale them  correctly if I set the parameter to a fixed value (say 2.0f or so) and re-compile my program. But I did not realize there would be a problem that you mentioned, thank you for the response.

Comment: Ok, can you post more code of your shader? and you are compiling this in a single Effect or are using separate shaders like ID3D11VertexShader, ID3D11GeometryShader...?

Comment: I edited my post. This is a single effect multiple pass rendering program. I didn't define shader variables in cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by rebuilding Vertex buffer and Stream-output buffer everytime after I modified the parameters, but I still don't know what exactly causes this problem.